# How to split list into sublists of zeros and nonzero values

Tags: python, list, split

For this given list:

```py
a = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0,
     1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1,
     0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5]
```

I would like to split the list into sublists of zeros and nonzero values to have the desired output of

```
a = [[1], [0,0], [1,1,1,3], [0],
     [1,1,3,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,],
     [0], [1], [0], [1,1,1], [0,0,0], [1,5]]
```

I know how to split a list into a certain length of sublists, but I don't think I can use that method here...

Comment: So the desired output would be.

[non-zero], [grouped zeroes], [none zeroes] etc.

all contiguous zeroes and non-zeroes end up in the same sublist for the output?

Comment: The two answers so far account for `x > 0`. Are you grouping numbers below zero with numbers above zero?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(a, lambda x:x>0)]
```

`groupby(a, lambda x:x>0)` groups successive 0 values or non-zero values together.

Above only handles non-negative values.  Improvement from FreddyMcloughlan comment to handle all integers.

```
a = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(a, lambda x:x!=0)]
```

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan -- good point.  I added that.

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan -- successive 0 values will be grouped together (since all False).  Also, successive non-zero values are grouped together (all True).  It works as-is on OP list `a`.

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan -- good point that it does not handle non-negative values.  See answer update.

Comment: @DarryIG, yeah I just realised my problem had the same issue

Answer (score 4):

You can just iterate over each value, and keep a buffer `c` and append the buffer to `b` when the element changes from `0` to a number `> 0`:

```
b = []
c = [a[0]]

for i in a[1:]:
    if (c[-1] > 0 and i > 0) or (c[-1] == 0 and i == 0):
        # Continue run
        c.append(i)
    else:
        b.append(c)
        c = [i]

b.append(c)
```

i.e. The conditional checks to see if the buffer `c` has changed from a non-zero array to a `> 0` array (and vice versa) and if it has not changed, you extend the buffer. When it has changed, append `c` to `b` (where `b` is the final array) then change the buffer to the next value `i`.

---

**Edit**

Your example only includes positive and zero values. If by "nonzero" you are including negative numbers with positive numbers, you can use:

```
b = []
c = [a[0]]

for i in a[1:]:
    # Use != 0, rather than > 0
    if (c[-1] != 0 and i != 0) or (c[-1] == 0 and i == 0):
        # Continue run
        c.append(i)
    else:
        b.append(c)
        c = [i]

b.append(c)
```

```
# Negative values:
>>> a = [1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, 3, 0,
...      1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1,
...      0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 5]
# Run algorithm above
>>> b
[[1], [0, 0], [1, -1, 1, 3], [0],
 [1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0], [1], [0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 5]]
```